# How to know if new message is different from previous message in a subscribed rostopic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, my question might be very basic. I have a subscriber node that is subscribing to a topic from a publisher. Now, the publisher might keep publishing same message over and over again while occasionally sending a new message to the topic. I want a functionality in my subscriber node that does the following:

```
if new message received is different from previous message in the topic:
       do something
else (if same message received again)
       do nothing
```

Can anyone direct me how to do this, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270696/how-to-know-if-new-message-is-different-from-previous-message-in-a-subscribed-rostopic?/) by [medhijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/31858/medhijk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-09-11**:
Have you written the publishing node? Your approach sounds like solving the wrong problem.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2017-09-11**:
What is difference between "same" message and "new" message? If the publisher processes something and issues a message that happens to have the same value as the previous message, is that a "new" message or a "same" message?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-09-12**:
I suspect it would be the same message for him and that his problem could be solved by a latched publisher.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-12**:
This is basically a level- vs edge-triggered signal problem (ie: publish always vs publish only on change).

@NEngelhard's suggestion of using a latched publisher is a good idea, but would require the publisher to not publish when there is nothing to publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @medhijk ,

the answer provided by @lmathieu works perfectly in C++.

If you need to do it in python, the concept is the same. I have created a video (https://youtu.be/U3fYcQwV1nY) that show how to do this in Python.

Below you have the code generated on the video. The subscriber subscribes to the `/chatter` topic and prints the received message only when the message is different from the previous one. If you still have any doubts, just take a look on the video.

The final code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String


last_msg = ''


def callback(data):
    
    global last_msg
    
    if data.data != last_msg:
        last_msg = data.data
        rospy.loginfo("I heard a DIFFERENT msg: %s", data.data)
    
    
def listener():

    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber("chatter", String, callback)

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

Ruben.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1